# Does using Retry attempt option SQL Agent job create performance issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-agent, jobs

I want to use Retry attempt option of sql agent job, want to know does it hold the resource and will create performance issue, if i keep it every 60 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The retry process itself does not use resources: it basically idles for the specified amount of time, then restarts the step. The step itself uses resources.

Comment: But in activity monitor it shows the status as "executing"..Does it mean it will reduce the sql performance @spaghettidba

Comment: Nope. It just idles.